# How to go from one view state to another view state in grails webflow plugin using glink tag?

Tags: grails

I have the following webflow representation with 2 view state

```
def createFlow = {
  startState {
    on("addItem"){
      //do something
    }.to "startState"

    on("deleteItem"){
      //do something
    }.to "startState"
  }

  secondState {
    on("addItem"){
      //do something
    }.to "startState"

    on("deleteItem"){
      //do something
    }.to "startState"
  }
}
```

In each view state i want to have a glink tag to call each other, I was trying this solution with no success

```
<g:link action="create" event="startState">Start</g:link>
<g:link action="create" event="secondState">Second</g:link>
```

I get

> No transition found on occurence of event 'startState' in state 'startState' of flow 'purchaseOrder/create' -- valid transitional criteria are array[addItem, deleteItem] -- likely programmer error, check the set of TransitionCriteria for this state

My question is, it is possible from a glink tag to call self view state or another view state?

Thanks for your time

Comment: In your example above, you don't have any way to transition to "secondState". Is that an artefact of the example or is it your problem? I would have expected to see a transition to "secondState" in the .to of at least one of the startState event handlers.

Comment: that is my question, if it is possible to straight

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use g:link to trigger an event.

The structure of your webflow should be something like this:

```
def createFlow = {
  startState {
    on("goToSecond"){
      //do something
    }.to "secondState"
  }

  secondState {
    on("goToStart"){
      //do something
    }.to "startState"
  }
}
```

In create/startState.gsp

```
<g:link action="create" event="goToSecond">Second</g:link>
```

In create/secondState.gsp

```
<g:link action="create" event="goToStart">Start</g:link>
```

The key things are:

1. You are always in a state and each state can handle one or more events.
2. You signal the event which causes the current state's event handler to fire and, if you set up this way, to move to another state.
3. Each state has a view that you use to signal the events using g:submit or g:link.

In your case you were trying to signal the state directly when you really wanted to signal the event name. Also, it looks like you were trying to do it from a single view. It is possible to bind a single view to multiple states (using a view override or using a template), but it doesn't really make much sense to do so.